# Display shipping methods to frontend as in the admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce, I'm doing the form of adding / changing product (at the front-end). I need to display the fields for changing the cost of delivery of the installed methods as  in the admin panel.

How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
<form>
<!-- Various input fields -->

<?php foreach ($shipping_methods as $method) { ?>
  <lebel>
    <h3><?php echo $method ?></h3>
    <input type="number" value="<?php //hook for input - output to make changes of shipping price of this method??Which one ?>">
  </lebel>
<?php } ?>

<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? "Save" : "Add"; ?> Product">
</form>
```

Comment: You should change `<lebel>` to `<label>` in your code first…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, thx, but page layout did not break. What do about hooks?

Comment: Now if you want to get everything like in shipping backend settings, you will need to: 1. Get the shipping zones… 2. For each shipping zone you will get the available Shipping methods… 3. For each shipping method you can have shipping classes rates… **So this is quite much more complicated…**

Comment: You should look to the code in `plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-shipping.php` … it should be useful for you as this is mostly the code involved in WooCommerce >settings > shipping …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shipping Methods are connected to a Shipping Zone, WooCommerce need to know which is the customer shipping zone. So your script will not work in a correct way until you get that information.

> To get that information, customer needs to logged in or if is not logged in it should need to add a product in cart…

Now the correct code to make your script working is:

```
// (temporary defining $edit_action for test purpose)
// To be removed and replaced by yours
$edit_action = true;
?>
<form>
    <!-- Various input fields -->

    <?php

    // Get the active shipping methods (Customer is logged in or cart is not empty)
    $rates = WC()->session->get("shipping_for_package_0")['rates'];
    if( ! empty($rates) ){
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            $method_id = $rate->method_id; // The method ID slug
            $instance_id = $rate->instance_id;
            $rate_id = $rate_key; // The rate ID (made of: $method_id + ':' + $instance_id)
            // Or $rate_id = $rate->id;
            $label = $rate->label; // The method ID Label
            $cost = $rate->cost;
            $taxes_array = $rate->taxes;
        ?>
        <label>
            <h3><?php echo $label ?></h3>
            <input type="number" value="<?php echo number_format($cost, 2); ?>">
        </label>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? "Save" : "Add"; ?> Product">
</form>
```

Tested and works *(only when the customer shipping zone is defined)*…

---

> Now if you want to get everything like in shipping backend settings, you will need to:

1. Get the shipping zones
2. For each shipping zone you will get the available Shipping methods
3. For each shipping method you can have shipping classes rates

So this is quite much more complicated…

---

Here is the way to start, but I didn't find the way to get/set cost as it's different for each shipping method type…

```
// Initializing variable
$zones = array();

// Rest of the World zone
$zone                                              = new \WC_Shipping_Zone(0);
$zones[$zone->get_id()]                            = $zone->get_data();
$zones[$zone->get_id()]['formatted_zone_location'] = $zone->get_formatted_location();
$zones[$zone->get_id()]['shipping_methods']        = $zone->get_shipping_methods();

// Merging shipping zones
$shipping_zones = array_merge( $zones, WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones() );

foreach ( $shipping_zones as $shipping_zone ) {
    // Row output (for testing)
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($shipping_zone); echo '</pre>';

    $zone_id = $shipping_zone['id'];

    $zone_name = $zone_id == '0' ? __('Rest of the word', 'woocommerce') : $shipping_zone['zone_name'];
    $zone_locations = $shipping_zone['zone_locations']; // (It's an array)
    $zone_location_name = $shipping_zone['formatted_zone_location'];
    $zone_shipping_methods = $shipping_zone['shipping_methods'];

    foreach ( $zone_shipping_methods as $shipping_method_obj ) {
        // Row output (for testing)
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($shipping_method_obj); echo '</pre>';

        echo $shipping_method_obj->id.'<br>';
        echo $shipping_method_obj->get_instance_id().'<br>';
        echo $shipping_method_obj->get_rate_id().'<br>';
        echo $shipping_method_obj->get_method_title().'<br>'; // Generic name
        echo $shipping_method_obj->get_title().'<br>'; // Customized name
    }
}
```

The class that make the Shipping cost is [**`WC_Shipping_Rate`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html)

---

Other related recent answer: [Display shipping cost on product page - WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409734/display-shipping-cost-on-product-page-woocommerce/47447817#47447817)

Comment: Thank you very much! But where can I specify the delivery zone?

Comment: I am making changes, clicking button "Submit". But shipping prices don't change.

Comment: @Александр because all shipping data like costs are cached… so you need to find out the way to refresh shipping cached data… This is an advanced development… So it's going to be very difficult for you to get this working… I can't help on this anymore than that.

Comment: Thank you very much once more. Good luck!)